# Creating a dictionary that maps an object to the amount of times it occurs in a list? In Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, list-comprehension

So basically i want each unique object to be a key and I want the corresponding value to be the number of times that object occurs in the list...

```
What I have: [obj1, obj2, obj2, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj4]
What I want: {obj1 : 1, obj2 : 3, obj3 : 1, obj4 : 2}
```

I know how I would do this with a for loop, but is there a better way or a more pythonic way using comprehensions or something? Thanks!

Comment: Note that you'll need all objects in your list to be hashable for this to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) was designed explicitly for this task:

```
from collections import Counter
lst = [obj1, obj2, obj2, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj4]
counter = Counter(lst)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
>>> counter = Counter(lst)
>>> counter
Counter({2: 3, 4: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1})
>>> counter[1]
1
>>> counter[2]
3
>>> counter[3]
1
>>> counter[4]
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
>>> s = set(l)   # s is now set([1,2,3,4])
>>> {i: l.count(i) for i in s}
{1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2}
```